# Can't load saved games in my hangman project

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am working in a hangman project in order to complete 
[the odin project curriculum](http://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-programming/lessons/file-i-o-and-serialization?ref=lnav)

The game works, but I am completely lost in the loading a saved game part.

[Here is the link to the project](https://github.com/EduardoMaldonado/hangman)

How do I recover the variables in order to continue the game?

Why when I load the game and put a letter to guess, the "each.with.index" method gives me a error?

What to do, in order to make my code load a game?

```
require "yaml"

class Play
attr_accessor :random_word

def main_menu
    puts "------------------------------------------------------"
    puts "------------------------------------------------------"
        loop do 
        puts "Please select,: (N)ew game, (L)oad, (E)xit"
        choice=gets.chomp.upcase
        case choice
        when "N"
            new_game 
            break
        when "L"
            load
        when "E"
            puts "\nthanks for playing! see you soon!"
            exit        
        else
            puts "\nPlease select 'N' for new game, 'L' to load an existing game, or 'E' to exit"
        end
    end
end

def save_game
    directory_name = "saved_games"
    Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name) #if "saved_games folrder doesnt exist create one"
    puts "\nSelect a name to save your game"
    save_name=gets.chomp
    File.open("saved_games/#{save_name}.yaml","w").puts YAML.dump(self) #Save the information in another file
    puts "\nGame saved!"
end

def load
    display_saved_games
    puts "\nWrite the name of the saved game you want to load"
    load_game=gets.chomp
    if File.exists?("saved_games/#{load_game}.yaml")
        loaded_game=YAML::load(load_game)
        game_loop
    else
        puts "\nNo saved game with that name found, please try again"
        load
    end
end

def display_saved_games #Display avaiable saved games
    directory_name = "saved_games"
    Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)
    if Dir.glob('saved_games/*').empty?
        puts "No saved games found!"
        main_menu
    else
        puts "Found the following saved games"
        puts Dir.glob('saved_games/*').join("\n")
    end
end


def new_game #Generate a new word and set everything for a new game
    @random_number=rand(61406) #Generate a random number
    @random_word=File.readlines("5desk.txt")[@random_number].chomp.to_s.upcase #read the random number generated line
    @correct_position=@random_word.split(//) #split the word in individual letters
    @correct_guesses=Array.new #Create the list of the correct answers
    @incorrect_guesses=Array.new #Create the list of the incorrect answers
    @random_word.length.times {@correct_guesses<<"_ "} #It puts one underscore in guess array for each letter in word
    puts "\nThe secret word is..\n\n"
    @correct_guesses.each_with_index { |value, index| print @correct_guesses[index]} #draw underscores. one for each letter
    puts "\n\n"
    game_loop
end

def draw
    puts "=============================================================================\n"
    @correct_guesses.each_with_index { |value, index| print @correct_guesses[index]} #Current state of guessed correctly letters
    puts "\n\nLetters not in secret word: "
    @incorrect_guesses.each_with_index { |value, index| print @incorrect_guesses[index] + ", "} #letters guessed not in the word
end

def turn
    puts "\nSelect a letter or write 'SAVE' to save your game and continue it later, or 'EXIT' to end the game" #Ask for letter or to save the game
    try=gets.chomp.to_s.upcase #Reads the letter
    if try=="SAVE"
        save_game
    elsif try=="EXIT"
        puts "\n\n\nThanks for playing, see you soon!"
        exit
    else
        check_correct(try) #Check if correct
    end
end

def check_correct(try)
    guessed_right=false
    @correct_position.each_with_index do |value, index| #matches each letter with the guess attemp
        if try==value   
            @correct_guesses[index]=try #if they are equal, deletes underscore and puts the correct letter
            guessed_right=true
        end
    end

    if guessed_right==false #if no letter was equal
            if @incorrect_guesses.include?(try)==false #put the letter to the incorrect guesses array just if not included before
                @incorrect_guesses<<try 
            else
                guessed_right=true #Avoid the counter to go down if select a repeated letter
                puts "\nYou already said that letter before!"
            end
    end
    return guessed_right
end

def check_win
    if @correct_guesses==@correct_position #it is a win if the guessed array is equal to the letters array
        return true
        puts "\n\n\nCongratulations!! you win!"
    else
        return false
    end
end

def game_loop #Game logic
    @turn_counter=0
    loop do
        while @turn_counter<10
            if turn==false
                @turn_counter+=1
                puts "You have #{10-@turn_counter} turns left!"
            end
            draw
            if check_win
                break
            end
        end
        puts "\n\n\n\nYou are out of turns, you lose!!!"
        puts "\n the secret word was #{@random_word}"
        break
    end
end
end

start=Play.new.main_menu
```

Comment: You're calling `each_with_index` on `@correct_position` which you've only defined for new games. You need to define `@correct_position` when loading an existing game.

Comment: Please add the code to the body of the question, not as external links that can expire, might be located on sites that are down or end up deleted, or are controlled by unknown third parties. You can edit your question to add any code that's relevant to the question at hand that helps people investigate, reproduce and resolve your problem.

Comment: Try changing YAML::load to YAML::load_file